# What's the difference between Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table & Replicate_Ignore_Table?

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, master-master-replication

In my site's master/slave setup:

- Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table = %.cache%, &
- Replicate_Ignore_Table is empty.

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table* option allows you to specify table names using wildcard characters. The *Replicate_Ignore_Table* option does not (only complete table names may be used).

See the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-replication-filter.html) for more details.